# How to determine X,Y position from point P based on time, velocity and rate of turn?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, derivatives, arc-length

We need to figure out an estimated position along an arc using a set of known variables. The starting position on the arc would be called point P, here are the known/measured variables:

> P = initial position of point P
>
> x = x coordinate of P (longitude)
>
> y = y coordinate of P (latitude)
>
> V = velocity of point P (nautical miles / min, or nautical miles / hour)
>
> H = heading / directional angle of point P in degrees (000 = North, 180 = South)
>
> R = rate of turn of P in degrees/minute.

All of those variables are known. We actually have a device that is able to calculate point P's rate of turn. [See this link here for the device](http://navicomdynamics.com/products/gyropilot).

We need to calculate the future X,Y positions of point P along the arc based on the variables above with respect to time. The dynamically changing variable to plug into the formula would be Time (in minutes or hours).

For example: at future time T, what would be the position of P (or Px1, Py1) along the arc. My thinking is that it would require some kind of calculus based derivative calculation. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure $R$ is not the rate of turning of $V$ rather than $P$?  If $P$ is the initial position, how does it have a rate of turning?

Comment: P is the antenna on a ship. R is the rate of turn of that ship, which would be the change in the ships gyro heading degrees / minute. So to me it seems it is the rate of turn of both, as V is the velocity of P. As P turns, V is moving with it.

Comment: Not very clear what the data really mean. If $V$ is the velocity as a vector (function of time) then it gives you all necessary information to compute the position starting at $P$. If $V$ is only the speed, but the heading is the instantaneous directional angle, then together they give you all information necessary to compute positions. The need to know $R$ (I presume it is the derivative of $H$) is not needed, unless you only know $H$ initially.

Comment: We need to compute future positions of P based on the starting point of P. We know the speed, heading, and rate of turn at the initial point P.

Comment: Are $V$, $H$ and $R$ constants? So the point is travelling with constant velocity and simultanously turning by a constant rate $R$?

Comment: I think we need a little more clarification for your variables and what they actually do. Feel free to drop me an email, Maybe chatting/talking about all this will help you faster.

Answer (score 2):

Let consider the coordinate $x$ first.
Set the origin of your coordinate system at the initial position $P$: the positive direction of the $x$ axis points to East, and time $t = 0$

At any point of time $t$, the $x$-coordinate of your ship will be given by 
$$ x(t) = \int_0 ^ t v(s) \cos\, \Big(\frac{\pi}{2} - h (s) \Big) \mathrm{d}s$$ where $h$ is the heading (converted to radians), and $v$ is the velocity.

What this hopefully does is get the value of the velocity, compute its projection with respect to the $x$-axis (the $\frac{\pi}{2}$ should take care of the different conventions used for angles, as sailors measure counterclockwise from the $y$ axis), and integrate.

Same for the $y$-coordinate 
$$ y(t) = \int_0 ^ t v(s) \sin\, \Big(\frac{\pi}{2} - h (s) \Big) \mathrm{d}s$$

You could also consider your point is moving on the complex plane, and wrap both the integrals in
$$ z(t) = \int_0 ^ t v(s) \exp \Bigg( i\Big( \frac{\pi}{2} - h (s) \Big) \Bigg) \mathrm{d}s$$
and now your $x$- and $y$-coordinates correspond to $\Re (z)$ and $\Im (z)$, the real and imaginary parts of $z$ respectively.

**EDIT FOLLOWING FURTHER CLARIFICATION**

It seems that my understanding of the proviced information was fallacious. It turns out that velocity is constant, as well as rate of turn.
The ship traces an arc of circumference, the radius $r$ of which satisfies the relationship $$ 2 \pi r = v \frac{2\pi}{R}$$ where $R$ is the rate of turn in radians / unit of time. 
The above equation simply states that the circumference (traced by a ship after a full round) equals the velocity times the time required for a 360 degress rotation.

The ship position vector $X$ as a function of time could be found by the parametric equations

$$X(t) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
    r \cos (tR + H)    \\
   r \sin (tR + H) 
 \end{array}
\right.
$$
to which a easy to figure correction should be added to account for the position $P$ at the beginning of the arc.

Comment: Can you please explain what each of the variables above mean?

Comment: Have added velocity $v$, and switched to $h$ for heading, i think they are all covered now. There are two integrals giving you the $x$ and $y$- coordinate as a function of time, given the functions $v(t)$ and $h(t)$ descriing how velocity and heading vary over time.

Comment: What is the meaning of the ds?

Comment: @wayofthefuture, $s$ is the Integration variable, and $\mathrm{d}s$ is part of the standard notation for definite integrals, $\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d}x$, do you recognise such notation?

Comment: @wayofthefuture, I appreciate you are not satisfied by my answer: should you wish to point at where it seems wrong / unconvincing to you, I would be glad to improve it.

Comment: It's not about satisfaction. I have no way to cross-check this with any official references. That is the purpose of the bounty... your time is appreciated thanks.

Comment: No worries, you do well to get a check and confirmation, I am no official source for sure, and my credibility is admittedly rather poor....

Comment: I've spent some time looking at this, and I don't think it applies. The key variable is rate of turn in degrees / minute and I don't see it in the formula. I don't understand how the equations above can predict the position along an arc if they are not taking into account the rate of turn. I know the initial velocity, heading, and rate of turn. All 3 of those variables I think should be required in the equation.

Comment: After some more reading I'm thinking the solution has more to do with angular displacement...

Comment: my thinking is to calculate the radius using w=V/r, then calculate angle via A=wt, then use simple trig to calculate x and y using rcosA and rsinA. Thoughts?

Comment: are you telling me that $V$ is a constant? And heading H out is also a constant, the initial heading? the formula above applies when both $V$ and $H$ are variable, and known as a function of time. In that case the rate of turnis redundant, as it is simply the derivative of $H$.  If on the other hand $V$ is constant, and $H$ is the initial heading only and the rate of turn is known, and also constant, then indeed you are sailing on a circumference

Comment: Is the rate of turn calculated with respect to compass heading or inertial frame? If this is a true navigation Problem , a Little bit of care has to be taken with defyning what a circumference is.

Comment: The linear velocity V is known at the start of the turn. The initial heading and initial angular velocity is also constant (rot). Rate of turn is calculated in degrees / minute using a device with silicon sensors. I think the above equation doesn't apply in our case. I think I have figured it out by calculating the radius of the circle based of the linear and angular velocity, then using time to determine delta radians and calculate the new x,y position along the arc. (v = rw, w = a/t)

Comment: ok then, I misinterpreted your Problem. I add an edit in the main post, just for completeness.